# How do I edit OSX PATH?

Tags: macos, path, command-line-interface

How do I edit OSX PATH?

I am installing the Play Framework (Activator) for Eclipse Luna in order to build Spark applications in Scala and then visualize in Play.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing

But after doing this, when I do $ activator -help it does not show up.

Here is my PATH:

```
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/Documents/Spark/Activator
```

Here is the test:

```
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ activator -help
-bash: activator: command not found
```

Comment: Following the README, I launched the Activator browser UI which runs on port 8888.  That means it is installed OK on my machine.  But I still do not know how to use it within Eclipse.  I am going to continue to try the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Path temporarily. This is explained below. This will be active only for the active terminal session.

Execute the following echo command in terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

This will output the existing paths. Copy paste the existing paths, add the path you need to add to it, separated by ":" (this is evident from the existing paths) and assign it to new path. Command given below

```
PATH=<list of new paths separated by:>
```

For example,

```
server:~ myMac$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin

server:~ myMac$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/myname/Documents/Spark/Activator
```

If you need to add it permanently, you have to edit ~/.bash_profile file. It is explained here - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

Comment: That doesn't help for gui applications on OS X launched by double clicking.  They don't use a shell or shell initialization files.